# Serial communication buffer data out of order

Tags: c, gtk, arduino

I'm trying to implement a simple SLAM project with Arduino and C on Linux Mint 15.
The Arduino project is sending data to notebook via bluetooth (serial). The data is read by a C program. In Arduino serial, the data is shown correctly, but in the notebook, the received data is wrong. (In image, white is Arduino data. The terminal shows the 'received' data.)

I'm sending `d080x096y099z035` (for example) and receiving `99z0356y0999z035` (out of order?).

So, I have some questions:

1. What can I do to make the `read()`command in C, read the data in the correct order and length? (order: `d000x000y000z000`, length = 16)
2. In the Arduino sending function, are there length differences using `Serial.print(char buffer[])` and `Serial.println(char buffer[])`? (Like adding a `'\n'` or something else at the end of buffer?)
3. Should I use the `delay()` function in the Arduino code or in the C code?

In Arduino:

```
...
int buffer_size = 17;
char  buffer[17];

//void setup()

void loop(){
  //create the string resp = "d000x111y222z333"
  ...
  resp.toCharArray(buffer, buffersize);
  bluetooth.print(buffer);
  delay(200);
}
```

In C program:

```
...
int fd = open("/dev/rfcomm4", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
printf("fd code %d\n", fd);
if (fd == -1)
{
  gchar *msg = "open_port: Unable to open /dev/rfcomm4";
  gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), msg);
  perror("error: ");
}

char buffer[17];
int n;

printf("entering in loop...\n");

while (1)
{
  n = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Comment: Your English is fine and you've articulated your question well.

Comment: You are missing one of most important parts: `//create the string resp = "d000x111y222z333"`! Post code for this!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not an expert but just a few ideas you might check concering your questions:

to 1) I guess it might be a problem with encoding, as Python AFAIK expects files to be unicode. So try `open (.... ,encoding='ascii')` or whatever encoding you use

Please also pay attention that you might block the GTK mainthread, that causes heavy delays in your UI. So I recommend creating a own thread for reading the serial port and filling an internal buffer, that get's rendered by the GTK mainthread, if you send an update request:
http://www.pardon-sleeuwaegen.be/antoon/python/page0.html